# remove part of url and add additional content to the end using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove everything in the src after -C87LOjwkRw? and add rel=0 to the end. This information is being pulled in via the software product so I am unable to edit the html directly.

```
<iframe id="VideoContent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="293" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-C87LOjwkRw?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fgif.test.org&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
```

I was thinking i could use url.split('?')[0] but am not sure how i can store the src.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a replace on it.

```js
let iframe = document.querySelector('#VideoContent');
let srcValue = iframe.getAttribute('src');
console.log('existing', srcValue);
srcValue = srcValue.replace(/\?.*$/, '?rel=0');
console.log('changed', srcValue);
iframe.setAttribute('src', srcValue);
```

```html
<iframe id="VideoContent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="293" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-C87LOjwkRw?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fgif.test.org&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a src attribute with jQuery:

```
let src = $(“#VideoContent”).attr(“src”);
$(“#VideoContent”).attr(“src”,src.replace(“enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fgif.test.org&amp;widgetid=1”,”rel=0”));
```